# How to intgegrate AFNetworking in my app for cache images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching, afnetworking

I am using table view with custom cell. and I want to store images in cache.
Here is my code:
**My table view Delegate method**:

```
 - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    LiveCameraCell* cell = ( LiveCameraCell* )[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"livecameracell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error dequeuing prototype cell");
    }else{
        cell.cameraData = [self getCamera:tableView forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CameraData*) getCamera:(UITableView*)tableView forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    CameraData* cameraData = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cameraData = (CameraData*) [searchResultsCameras objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cameraData = (CameraData*) [allCameras objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cameraData;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    LiveCameraCell* liveCameraCell = (LiveCameraCell*)cell;
    CameraData* cameraData = [self getCamera:tableView forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    liveCameraCell.mapButton.hidden = [cameraData hasGeoLocation] ? NO : YES;

    if (![cameraData isSnapshotLoaded] && ![cameraData isLoadingImage]) {
        /*[cameraData loadImageAsync1:^{
            liveCameraCell.cameraImage.image = cameraData.snapshotImage;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        }];*/
        [cameraData loadImageAsync1:^(UIImage* image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //NSLog(@"Image load");
                if (![cameraData isThumbnailCachedWithHeight:[self thumbnailHeight] width:[self thumbnailWidth]])
                {
                    if(cameraData.name == cameraData.name)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Image load");
                        [liveCameraCell showThumbnail:cameraData.snapshotImage];
                        //liveCameraCell.cameraImage.image = cameraData.snapshotImage;

                    }
                }
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
                [cell setNeedsDisplay];
            });
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        if (![cameraData isThumbnailCachedWithHeight:[self thumbnailHeight] width:[self thumbnailWidth]])
        {
            if (cameraData.snapshotImage !=liveCameraCell.cameraImage.image) {
            liveCameraCell.cameraImage.image = cameraData.snapshotImage;
            }
        }
        /*[cameraData downloadThumbnailWithHeight:[self thumbnailHeight] width:[self thumbnailWidth] callback:^(UIImage* thumbnail) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [liveCameraCell showThumbnail:thumbnail];
            });
        }];*/
    }
    liveCameraCell.label.text = cameraData.name;
    liveCameraCell.description.text = cameraData.description;

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The all work are done in my `willDisplayCell:` method.
And here is my another methods which are used in `willDisplayCell:`:

```
-(void)loadImageAsync1:(void (^)(UIImage*))callback {
    if (_snapshotImage) { callback(_snapshotImage); return; }
    _loadingImage = YES;
    HttpRequest* request = [HttpRequest requestWithRelativePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/v1/camera/%@/snapshot?width=64", _uuid]];
    [HttpResponse processAsynchronousRequest:request onCompletion:^(HttpResponse* response){
        _snapshotImage = [UIImage imageWithData:response.responseData];
        _loadingImage = NO;
        if (!_snapshotImage) _snapshotImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gray_thumbnail_background.png"];
        callback(_snapshotImage);
    }];
}
```

Please help to integrate this library. I already added classes in my project.
Now, what next?
How to add this in `willDisplayCell:`?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use afnetworkings afnetworking+uiimageView class which provide a direct method to fetch image from url and cache them in memory for you... like this.. [imageView setImageforUrl:url placeholderImage:yourimage];

Comment: yes I know. but how to use this in my willDisplayCell?

Comment: because I already try this.

Comment: No i am not using database. so please tell me ho to use this in my willDisplayCell method ?

Comment: currently there is only one issue image change after scrolling only at first time. is there any solution for that caching is working but the main issue is image change while scrolling?

Comment: just put it into the place u work with your customcell eg `cellForRow` method

Comment: yeah this issue occurs when we scroll fastly..... for this in your willDisplayCell method... just put this code before loading images... that yourImageView.image = nil;.... hope this will help you

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. But it's not working I already try this.

Answer (score 0):

store all url's in an array according to no. of cells
and then in willDisplayCell Method just do like that

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

       [youCellImageView setImagewithUrl:[arrayUrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] placeholderImage:"placeHOlderImage"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage Library and using the following method you can download images.

```
[cell.imgProductImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] valueForKey:@"variant_image"]]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
```